# cannot convert to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: dataframe reference]

```
import pandas as pd

#initialize data frame from original excel file
#specify required columns from dataset
req_columns = [4,5,6, 9]
df = pd.read_excel('Flt0052UV.xlsx', skiprows = range(1,33656), usecols= req_columns)
df['Local Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Local Time'], infer_datetime_format = True)
# times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.'Local Time')
# grouped = df.groupby([times.hour, times.minute])
df = df[~df.Longitude.isnull()]
df = df.resample('1min').first()
# filtered_data = df.loc[df['Longitude'] == 0]

print (df)
waypt=[]

#append list to fill with needed columns
for row in df:

    waypt.append(df['Local Time'])
    waypt.append(df['Altitude m'])
    waypt.append(df['Latitude'])
    waypt.append(df['Longitude'])

# print(waypt)
start = waypt[0]
```

Ok so for context I need to take one entry from the local time column per minute I tried to do this using resample but it didn't work due to the column not being datetime. However when I try to convert to datetime I get this error: [image]

any help is greatly appreciated I'm new to pandas but have experience with SQL.

Comment: i can only guess `df = df.resample('1min').first()` causes the error. as `resample` is used on the Index... so try to use `df = df.set_index('Local Time')` before `resample`

Comment: can't be that because I can't convert to datetime when that line is not included

Comment: ` The object must have a datetime-like index (DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex, or TimedeltaIndex),` : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html
so check if your `df['Local Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Local Time']` did the job, set it as index, also not sure about `.first()` parameter (is it usable) during resampling